# In terms of memory usage, what is the difference between these two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, undefined

Here i have an array with elements whose indexes are separated by increments of 1.

```
let noGap = [];
noGap[0] = 0;
noGap[1] = 1;
```

Here I have a different array whose indexes are separated by indexes of much greater than 1.

```
let gap = [];
gap[0] = 0;
gap[1000] = 1;
```

What is the difference between how much memory each variable (`noGap` vs `gap`) uses? I can see from a Chrome console log that `gap` has wider length, because it logs  `(1001) [0, undefined × 999, 1]`.

But **if** the `gap` variable indeed uses more space, I'm interested to know if it's proportionate to the number of `undefined` that exist in the array or if it's constant.

Pardon me if this is repeated question. This is the [closest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596081/do-undefined-values-in-javascript-arrays-use-any-memory-or-get-iterated-over-in) I found but I couldn't fully understand the answer.

Comment: "*…because there are 999 'undefined' in there*". No, there aren't. There are two members and a length of 1001.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321047/how-are-javascript-arrays-represented-in-physical-memory

Comment: Really depends on the JS engine and the number of times this code is run - see hotspot optimization / optimizing compiler. The second array with holes will probably be backed by a hash table with certain overhead while the first will be stored as a compact 32-bit signed integer array. Both perform preallocation.

Comment: Internet Exploder shows `0` then 999 actual `undefined` values then `1` - firefox shows `0, 999 empty slots, 1`, chrome says `0, 999 x undefined, 1` (is that how chrome shows empty slots?) - so ... which browser are you referring to

Comment: thanks, all. i used chrome. edited my post for clarity. also thank you @TommyMay I knew there was a preceding post somewhere that I probably missed.

Answer (score 0):

**In V8, there is a big difference, the long and sparse array takes more memory.** However, this is partially because 1000 is near the boundary after which V8 changes its internal representation of sparse arrays.  **An even longer sparse array will likely take a similar amount of memory.**

I only did a little evidence gathering with the Chrome dev tools (check out the memory tab), but here it is. Each row in this table is an array with an entry at index `0`, and another at the end to define its length.

```
| sparse array length | retained size |
|---------------------|---------------|
| 1                   | 56            |
| 10                  | 304           |
| 1000                | 12,184        |
| 2000                | 184           |
| 3000                | 184           |
| 3000, less sparse   | 472           |
```

Notice that memory scales with length up to 1000, but at 2000 it's much less, and it scales with number of set indices instead.

I'm *assuming* this is because V8 is switching from a complete representation of all the values from indices `0` to `length` (in the case of length 1000) to a hash map which only has entries for the indices which have been set.

I have no formal knowledge of how this actually works, FYI.